# Check if string is similar to another string in php?

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I need to check if `$string1 == $string2` but I dont want it to matter if ones uppercase and the other is lowercase, for example I would like `if (harrisburg == HARRISBURG)` to return true! What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Did you consider changing the case of both to Upper and then comparing?..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strtolower($string1) == strtolower($string2)`

Comment: Perfect, but strcasecmp() function is faster. if you want to use it with loops in big data reading. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

`strcasecmp ( string $str1 , string $str2 )`  ignoring the case, returns 0 if they're equal

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
$str1 = 'harrisburg';
$str2 = 'HARRISBURG';
```

**Option-1:** If `$str2` value is uppercase.

```
strtolower('$str2');
```

for more details [strtolower — Make a string lowercase](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php)

**Option-2:** Case-insensitive string comparision

```
strcasecmp ($str1 ,$str2)
```

for maore details [strcasecmp — Binary safe case-insensitive string comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php)

**Note(for option-2)**: `Returns < 0 if str1 is less than str2; > 0 if str1 is greater than str2, and 0 if they are equal.`

may this help you.

Comment: Is solution need to use regex when we already have strtolower, strcasecmp is available :)

Answer (score 1):

```
strcmp ( strtolower($str1) , strtolower($str2))
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is a function for this in PHP? This function will return the value of similarity between the two strings passed. Not exactly what the OP was asking for but thought would be a relevant answer considering the question title.

[similar_text(str1, str2)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php)